# 'Describe this object to me' - To work out what type of thought process you have. What is this test called?

Tags: personality, test

A friend learned heard about a test while on a Myers Briggs course and described it to me.  I thought it was interesting, but I can't find anything about it since I don't know what to search for.

The instructor says 'tell me about this [object]'

One type of person will say a few factual observations

> It's a red book

Another type will give you a firehose of information

> People learn things from it, it's old so its probably had a few people read it, they probably really loved the book, ...

Is there a well known test like this? Is there anything term I can google to learn more?

There is a discussion of it here too.
https://www.thisamericanlife.org/731/what-lies-beneath/act-two-5

Answer (score 1):

The test you seem to be talking about is often referred to by different names, but the name used by The Myers & Briggs Foundation[1] and most of the papers on the subject[2] is MBTI (Myers-Briggs Type Indicator).

PS:

1. I did my best to identify it according to your description, but leave a comment if it's not the test you had in mind.
2. It is important to add that this test is often regarded as pseudoscience and has several fundamental issues [3]

[1] https://www.myersbriggs.org/my-mbti-personality-type/mbti-basics/
[2] https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=%22Myers-Briggs+Type+INdicator%22&btnG=
[3] https://www.psychologytoday.com/intl/blog/give-and-take/201309/goodbye-mbti-the-fad-won-t-die